# AS3: create template for XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I need to create DB report as excel file. The best (and simplest) way I can see - create the XML representation and save it as XLS.
The Header and Footer parts of this file should be constant, so I'd prefer to load them from config (or template) file instead of hard coded string constants.
And it has no sense to use the XML per se - the "string" will be more than enough.
The question is: how I can do it? I mean - load XML content as string, or as a last resort - create string constant.
I've tried what was recommended for multi-line constants in one of stackoverflow answers (use CDATA). But seems, for XML content it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **URLLoader** will load any file as String by default. Otherwise, use XML for XML data, not XML string packed into CDATA of other XML (if I understand your thought correctly).

Comment: Thanks. Think, it's what I looked for. I'll try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Organis You should post this comment as an answer, so this may be accepted. No? ;)

Comment: @tatactic It's not actually an answer, just a push into the right direction.

Comment: @Organis Actually tactic is right - I tried to answer you but it looks like I'm trying to answer my own question, that is not a case. I'd like to note your comment as right answer on my question.

Comment: @Gena Sure, if that helped to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**URLLoader** will load any file as String by default. Otherwise, use XML for XML data, not XML string packed into CDATA of other XML (if I understand your thought correctly).